# Using codeigniter library in php

Tags: codeigniter

Y have external php library and i want to use codeigniter lang library to recover one translation
How i can do it?

I have tried:

```
define('BASEPATH', realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) .'admin/system/');
include(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) . '/admin/system/libraries/Language.php');
echo 'line' . line('servicios'); exit;
```

Thanks

Comment: Start at [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html).

Comment: What is your librarie name? Where do you extract it? What error are you getting?